# is it possible to automate series of git operations with grunt?

Tags: git, gruntjs

It would be great if I could automate series of git commands like this: http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2011/02/git-merge-strategytheirs.html

I have made some a attempts using: https://github.com/rubenv/grunt-git
But I'm not sure if it's entirely doable.

Is using grunt for this a good idea?

Comment: Please make the question self-contained, so that it's still readable if the link should die. Also: Why are you not sure grunt fits the task?

Answer (score 0):

On the grunt homepage it says

> With literally hundreds of plugins to choose from, you can use Grunt to automate just about anything with a minimum of effort.

And guess what (you already seem to know this)- a grunt plugin for this purpose already exists: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-git

It's very extensive and well documented.

> Is using grunt for this a good idea?

Maybe, maybe not. But over 10,000 users are already using this plugin so using grunt for git tasks can't be that wrong ;-)